# bag bootstrap Tooltip remains on page sometimes

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap for one of the project and facing an issue with tooltip plugin.I have two tags div:

```
  <div class='Tracked StarInDisplay' title='Прибор отслеживается' rel='tooltip'   onClick='Device($(this),""{0}"",{1})'></div>
```

and

```
<div title='Отслеживать прибор' class='StarInHide' rel='tooltip'   onClick='Device($(this),""{0}"",{1})'></div>.
```

When you click on the first div is replaced by second div .And vise versa.  Part of the script

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { prodN: prodn, kpr: kpr },
    success: function (result) { $elem.replaceWith(result); $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({ html: true }); }
```

The issue is:
Tooltip works normally.But When we click on div and then moves mouse out of  div - the tooltip doesn't gets hidden and stays over there on the page.
How can we fix this?
Sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mouseleave event on this div. In this event you can use tooltip('hide')